# Open multiple instances of same partial view and controller in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, partial-views, angular-controller, singlepage

I am developing single page application using partial views and angularJS. 
I am having a scenario where I have to open same partial view multiple times with different data.

I tried to make controller name dynamic by adding app.directive and changing controller name both in js and html and then calls Angular-Complies method, but the issue is that it changes it for all previous tabs opened.
Then I tried to make multiple js files and changing controller name in partial view with Jquery but still does not helps. Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <!-- this is in view1.html -->
    <div ng-controller="DashboardDesignerController">
            <div ng-repeat="widget in workspace.widgets">stuff here
            </div>
   </div>
    <!-- this is in view1.html -->
    <div ng-controller="DashboardDesignerController">
            <div ng-repeat="widget in workspace.widgets">stuff here
            </div>
   </div>
```

//Angular controller is in separate JS file.

```
   app.controller("DashboardDesignerController" , function ($scope, $http, 
   $rootScope, $compile, $injector, $timeout) {
   }
```

I expect to behave every tab separately according to its data but currently when I go to first opened tab, it's scope changed with the last opened tab.
Is there built in way of angularJS to doing it, Or some good approach will also appreciated.

Comment: Is the number of times you have to replicate your controller fixed, or can it by dynamic?

Comment: Not fixed, Its dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the issue was, I was calling chart drill down method in core JavaScript which was replacing $scope with last opened. 
Resolved the issue by getting scope with JQuery

```
var scope= angular.element($('.k-state-active').find('.tempDiv')[0]).scope();
```

and called angular function with this scope variable.